Single click clears selection of QML TreeView
I'm using Qt6.5 and I want to implement selection on QML TreeView, as the default interaction seems to only support navigation (involving the current property, which is a different concept from selected). So my QML code looks like this:
TreeView {
    model: MySingletonController.model
    selectionBehavior: TableView.SelectRows
    selectionModel: ItemSelectionModel {
        model: model
    }
    delegate: TreeViewDelegate {
        required property int index
        contentItem: Text {
            text: parent.index + " " + parent.current + " " + parent.selected
        }
        onDoubleClicked: {
            selectionModel.select(
                treeView.index(index, 0),
                ItemSelectionModel.Select
            )
        }
    }
}

Note that I implement selecting on double-click events. Also note that the treeView.index method is from TableView and I use it to get the QModelIndex.
This seems to work until I notice that any single mouse click (on the previously selected item, on some other unselected item, or just on the blank space) within the TreeView would just clear the selection. Why does it behave that way and how can I fix it?
Tracking the slot calls using a custom QItemSelectionModel, I found that a single click on the TreeView, when the selection is not empty, would trigger a call to void QItemSelectionModel::select(const QItemSelection &selection, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags command) with an empty selection and a Clear command. Maybe this has something to do with the TableView's interaction logics?

Ok, I find this in doc for TableView:

Note: By default, a cell will become current, and any selections will be removed, when the user taps on it. If such default tap behavior is not wanted (e.g if you use custom pointer handlers inside your delegate), you can set pointerNavigationEnabled to false.

So this explains everything.
And it seems that with pointer-navigation disabled, the TreeView's node-expanding behavior would also be disabled. A branch node now wouldn't expand when I click on the indicator of the delegate. Maybe I would have to reimplement the delegate.
